# Determining the sequence that yields a balanced search tree in the form of a recurrence / sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, computer-science

Let's say I have a sequence of (distinct) monotonically increasing numbers `S`. I'll want to add them sequentially to a Binary Search Tree (BST) but as the numbers are monotonically increasing the resulting tree will be unbalanced (the tree will be nothing but a linked-list).

To correct this problem, I can devise another sequence `S'` containing all the elements of `S` but in a different order. For instance, if $S = { 1..9 }$, then $S' = { 5, 2, 7, 1, 3, 6, 8, 4, 9 }$ would yield a balanced tree were I to add all these integers to an initially empty BST. The formula I followed was informally

$a_{ij} = i + \frac{j-i+1}{2}$

It's easy for me to do this on paper or even to implement a function in a programming language that making use of a queue can yield `S'` from `S` (for an arbitrary value of `n`) but I'm quite lost on how to do this making use of either sequences or recurrences.

How would I go about "formalizing" this mathematically, without resorting to pseudo-code?

Comment: I'm a little confused with your formula because $a_{11}$ = 1+ $\frac {1}{2}$ = $\frac {3}{2}$ So, I think you need to set up initial conditions. Essentially, you're looking for a recurrence relation with a suitable initial condition. something like T(i,j) = whatever... and then show T(n) is just a rearrangement of $S'$. It is also fine to use the $max$ operator in your recurrence.

Comment: I forgot to point out, this is over the integers and I'm ceiling the results, so $a_{11}$ would turn out to be 1.

Comment: What does $a_{ij}$ represent? What is $i$ and $j$?